# What is the estimated S3 file loss percentage

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to communicate to a client the likely-hood of losing files in S3.  I would also like to know if it is possible to lose an entire bucket from S3.  So, I would like to know the following:

1. Is there a documented expected file loss percentage in S3?
2. Is there a documented expected bucket loss percentage in S3?

When I say "lose" a file.   I mean a file that is lost, damaged or otherwise unable to be pulled from S3.  This "loss" is caused by a failure on S3.  It is not caused by a tool or other user error.

Comment: Elaborate.  What do you mean "losing" - if the chance of files just disappearing in S3 is anything above 0% do you think anyone would use it?

Comment: @Gandalf: nothing is guaranteed (expect death & taxes): I believe, like any other real system, it falls under a probabilistic domain.

Comment: However it's possible that the event in question does not occur with enough frequency to get a probability for it.

Comment: apparently it's happened, but quite rare http://www.quora.com/Has-Amazon-S3-ever-lost-data-permanently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon doesn't give any kind of SLA or data loss guarantees for data stored on S3, but as far as I know nobody has ever lost any data on S3 aside from user/tool errors.

Comment: There _is_ a percentage of request failure, note - but this is not data loss; you just need to retry when you get a 5xx error.

Comment: They do have an SLA, but it covers uptime and not data loss. The SLA says of uptime failures "your sole and exclusive remedy for any unavailability or non-performance of Amazon S3 or other failure by us to provide Amazon S3 is the receipt of a Service Credit (if eligible)", and if they did provide an SLA for data loss it would likely be similar - i.e. you wouldn't get compensation for the loss incurred from losing data in any case.

Comment: Is this still current? On https://aws.amazon.com/s3/details/ they say "Designed for 99.999999999% durability and 99.99% availability of objects over a given year." This is not a guarantee but would answer the original question (even if it cannot be proven).

Answer (score 1):

I would say the probability of user / coder error causing data loss is substantially greater than data loss through some kind of failure on S3.  So you may wish to consider some kind of backup strategy to mitigate that.